# How to obtain prediction results in edward

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

Thank you for this community. I am a beginner and I have a very dumb question on using [Edward](http://edwardlib.org/). I am using a [tutorial](http://edwardlib.org/tutorials/batch-training) regression model. Everything is perfect. I was wondering how to obtain the prediction on testing set. for example, assuming

```
y = Normal(loc=neural_network(X), scale=0.1 * tf.ones(M), name="y")
```

How can I got y by giving testing set? I tried: `y.eval(feed_dict={X: x_valid})`. but the mean absolute error results seems not matched: the MAE using `ed.evaluate('mean_absolute_error', data={X: x_valid, y_post: y_valid})` is roughly 0.074, while the MAE from y.eval and y_valid is roughly 0.11.

I also tried `sess.run(y, feed_dict={X: x_valid})`, which is also not working.